# NULL in foreign key column(s)

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key

I have been learning about `SIMPLE` and `FULL` matching foreign keys in PostgreSQL and I am wondering if the following thought process is correct:

Once at least one of the referencing columns of the foreign key contains a `NULL` value, there is no link to the referenced table. This is because a `NULL` is not comparable with another `NULL` value, as per 3VL. This also means that defined cascading actions (such as `... DO DELETE`, `... DO SET NULL`, ..) when a referenced row which contains at least one `NULL` value in the relevant columns, is updated or deleted will never happen, because there is no link to the referenced row. More concrete, assume a foreign key from table `A(x, y)` to `B(x, y)`. If both `A` and `B` contain a row `(5, NULL)` for `x` and `y`, there is no link, because the `NULL` for the row in `A` is not equal to the `NULL` for the row in `B`.

Is this correct? I am quite new to SQL, so I am wondering if I understood this correctly.

Comment: It's not "because" of the reasons you give. It's because that's what the designers of SQL decided, because of a general vague motivation of associating NULL with a normal value of a type being unavailable or inapplicable. But the details are not consequences of any particular well-founded or unified theory or design. We must memorize how features act--although we can sometimes organize them in terms of simpler ideas. Example: A FK subrow with a NULL cannot match or be a duplicate of or SQL-equal a PK subrow. So the FK's constraint "should" fail using "normal" NULL reasoning. But it doesn't.

Comment: "there is no link" is not clear. Use technical terms, correctly. (It is best to never use "link".) You might be trying to say something about a FK subrow not appearing as a referenced PK subrow; but you might be trying to say something about a FK constraint failing or succeeding; or you might be trying to say something about both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are quite right. I have created a small example at [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=11b45f56d7f6f783ad2fea116f36983f)

```
create table p
( a int not null
, b int
, unique (a,b)
);

create table c
( a int not null
, b int
, constraint fk_p foreign key (a,b)
                  references p (a,b)
                      on delete cascade
                      on update cascade
);

-- insert data in parent:
insert into p (a,b) values (1,null);  -- ok
insert into p (a,b) values (1,null);  -- also ok. The constraint evaluates to null,
                                      -- which is ok. The rule is that it must not 
                                      -- evaluate to false

-- insert data in child
insert into c (a,b) values (1,null);  -- ok
insert into c (a,b) values (2,null);  -- also ok, foreign key evaluates to null. 
                                      -- So despite there is no 2 in
                                      -- parent this is ok

-- remove data from parent
delete from p;

-- all rows present in child
select * from c;

a   b
1   null
2   null
```

Null makes even trivial things a bit tricky to grasp. I would not recommend candidate keys that include nulls.

Comment: The fiddle is so interesting, I did not know something like that existed. Very easy to try out stuff! I am going to experiment some stuff and come back here!

Comment: Yes, there are also a couple of more alternatives out there. Very cool to able to try things in DBMS that you don't have installed locally.

Comment: Just great and very useful!